# How to optimize a SQL query showing 2 adjacent rows with closed in values timestamps?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need create a query for postgresql that shows requests made within 100 milliseconds.  The postgresql table request has request id (request_id) and timestamp(create_stamp).

Mu query below works but very slowly.

```
select
    b1.create_stamp as st1,
    b2.create_stamp as st2,
    b1.request_id as b1_id,
    b2.request_id as b2_id,
    Cast(date_part('milliseconds', b1.create_stamp) as Integer) as msi1,
    Cast(date_part('milliseconds', b2.create_stamp) as Integer) as msi2,
    (date_part('milliseconds', b1.create_stamp) - date_part('milliseconds', b2.create_stamp)) as diff
from
    request b1, request b2
where
    (b1.request_id - b2.request_id) = 1
    and (date_part('milliseconds', b1.create_stamp) - date_part('milliseconds', b2.create_stamp)) < 100
    and (date_part('milliseconds', b1.create_stamp) - date_part('milliseconds', b2.create_stamp)) > 0
order by b1.request_id;
```

Comment: Post your table definition?  Is there an index on `request_id` ?

Comment: What should happen if there are more than two adjacent records within the time window?

Comment: The table is rather complicated but only 2 columns are important: request_id (primary key - automatic index) and timestamp

Comment: Request_id is *not* important for this problem, IMHO. Only a surrogate. (could be needed as a tie-breaker, but I doubt if there are any ties in the data. And if they existed, other *payload* attributes should be needed to disambiguate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following query:

```
SELECT Q.*
FROM (
    SELECT *, lag (create_stamp, 1) OVER (ORDER BY request_id) prev
    FROM request
) Q
WHERE
    create_stamp - prev <= interval '00:00:00.1';
```

[[SQL Fiddle]](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/4192e/46)

It will return all rows such that there is a previous<sup>1</sup> row within 100 ms.

---

*<sup>1</sup> "Previous" as determined by the order of `request_id` - change ORDER BY clause appropriately if that's not what you want.*

Comment: Very good, thanks. Just in case interval '00:00:00.01' gives the difference of 10 milliseconds

Comment: @anarinsky Ugh, sorry. I missed the decimal place. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `lag()`/`lead()` to check previous and next values.  This should be much faster than a self-join:

```
select r.*
from (select r.*,
             lag(create_stamp) over (order by request_id) as prevcs,
             lead(create_stamp) over (order by request_id) as nextcs
      from request r
     ) r
where (date_part('milliseconds', r.create_stamp) - date_part('milliseconds', prevcs)) < 100 and
       date_part('milliseconds', r.create_stamp) - date_part('milliseconds', prevcs)) > 0
      ) or
     (date_part('milliseconds', nextcs) - date_part('milliseconds', r.create_stamp)) < 100 and
       date_part('milliseconds', nextcs) - date_part('milliseconds', r.create_stamp)) > 0
      )
```

The reason for using both `lag()` and `lead()` is to return both rows of a pair.  If the first such row is sufficient, then you only need one function (and half the `where` clause).

I notice that your original query looks at adjacent request ids.  Is this what you really want?  Or do you want to order the rows by `create_stamp`?  If so, change the `order by` argument in the partition by functions.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic . . . This actually uses the original logic from the question which the OP claimed was working.  You are correct, though, that it won't work at midnight.  Doing a date diff would be a better approach.

Comment: yes, the original logic was flawed for midnight- but all our activity is in the day time

Answer (score 0):

may be you can simply your query by using subquery

```
select b1.create_stamp as st1, b2.create_stamp as st2, b1.request_id as b1_id, 
b2.request_id as b2_id,     msi1, msi2, (msi1 - msi2) as diff 
from 
(
     select * , Cast(date_part('milliseconds', create_stamp) as Integer) as msi1
     from request 
) b1
,
(
     select * , Cast(date_part('milliseconds', create_stamp) as Integer) as msi2
     from request 
) b2 
where 
(b1.request_id - b2.request_id) = 1 and 
(msi1 - msi2) < 100 and (msi1 - msi2) > 0 
order by b1.request_id;
```